# Navigate to pages using jquery with urls that have hash and parameters

Tags: jquery, url, parameters, hashtag

I'm using jquerymobile.

Inside a page lets call it `page1.aspx` I have different sections like header, content, footer and navigate

So if i want to open the section navigate some href in other page `page2.aspx` must look like `href="page1.aspx#navigate"`

But how can I do the same but adding parameters? like `href="page1.aspx#navigate?param1=2&param2=3`, is this possible or how the syntaxis is?

Thank you.

Comment: But why do you need this parameters?

Answer (score 6):

Query params should come before hashtags in URLs, otherwise the query params will be counted as part of the hash tag.  Here is what you want:

```
href="page1.aspx?param1=2&param2=3#navigate"
```

Just as a reference, here is the spec:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

See section #4.2, it talks about how to construct relative links.

Comment: Does it mean if you have more than 1 params having `#`...the params after first instance of `#` will be ignored. Is there a way to get around this?